# How to put the rest of the list as 0 in python?

Tags: python

As the question stated, I have one list contains x elements.
For example the x is 4:

```
first_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to construct another list with a fix size of 8. This list will contain whatever first_data have. If the first_data do not have 8 elements, the rest of the elements will be 0.

Example:

```
final_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0 ,0, 0]
```

So far I have tried different methods but it didn't work.

How can I achieve this? Thanks and appreciate if any helps!

Comment: the size of the final list is grater or equal with the size of the first list?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 It will confirm greater than size of the first list

Comment: final_list = [*first_data, *[0] * (final_size - len(first_data)) ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following, making use of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
size = 8
final_data = first_data + [0] * max(0, size - len(first_data))
final_data
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

While this is very explicit, you can be more concise and use how `list` handles multiplication with negative numbers (e.g. `[0] * -3 == []`):

```
final_data = first_data + [0] * (size - len(first_data))
```

If you want to trim `first_data` down in case it is longer than size, just use `first_data[:size]` instead of `first_data` in any of the above examples.

Comment: omg I totally didn't think of using the length of the data! Thank you so much for the answer and editing of the question!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple.You can do it like this.

```
array = [0]*8
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array[:len(arr)] = arr
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Let `l` be your list

You can initialise `l` like so:

```
fixed_size = 8
l = [0] * fixed_size
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to know how many zeros are missing. to do so, compare the desired length to what you have:

```
from typing import List

def pad_with_zeros( initial: List, desired_len: int):

    zeros_to_add = desired_len - len(initial)

    if zeros_to_add > 0:
        padding = [0] * zeros_to_add
        return initial + padding
    else:
        # How do you want to handle the case when the initial list is longer than the desired output?
        pass
```

Then we create a new list of zeros, and extend the initial list using '+'. You will need to handle the case when initial list needs zero padding, or even is bigger than the desired fixed length.

Comment: I do not know how many zeros are missing because the list is accepted from user value, they can filling it within a range but not constant number.