# Format list of data points to display in graph

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I'm writing an API endpoint in Django Rest Framework and want to format data for a graph. I have data like this which I get from the database:

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "Test 3",
        "status": "Active",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "status": "Failed",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "status": "In Progress",
        "count": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "status": "Failed",
        "count": 40
    },
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "status": "Active",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "status": "Success",
        "count": 218
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "status": "Active",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I want to format the final graph data from above like this in order to show it in the graph:

```
[
    "labels": ['Test', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
    "data": [
        {
            name: 'Active',
            data: [1, 1, 1]
        },
        {
            name: 'Failed',
            data: [40, 1, 0]
        },
        {
            name: 'Success',
            data: [218, 0, 0]
        },
        {
            name: 'In Progress',
            data: [85, 0, 0]
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to format data in that way but I'm unable to do so. Are there any built-in functions that I can use to make the data format correct?

```
response = [
    {
        'labels': [],
        'data': [],
    }
]
for row in data:
    if row['name'] not in response[0]['labels']:
        response[0]['labels'].append(row['name'])
        innerData = []
        for status in ['Active', 'Failed', 'Success', 'In Progress']:
            if status in row['status']:
                innerData.append(row['count'])
            else:
                innerData.append(0)
        response[0]['data'].append(
            {
                'name': status,
                'data': innerData,
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Rustam's answer:

1. Add a dictionary `label_to_idx` to be used to determine the index by label.
2. Pass a `lambda` function to `defaultdict` to initialize lists of correct size and default value.
3. Populate `d` for each status, using `label_to_idx` to find the correct index to fill with count.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {"name": "Test 3", "status": "Active",      "count": 1},
    {"name": "Test 2", "status": "Failed",      "count": 1},
    {"name": "Test",   "status": "In Progress", "count": 85},
    {"name": "Test",   "status": "Failed",      "count": 40},
    {"name": "Test",   "status": "Active",      "count": 1},
    {"name": "Test",   "status": "Success",     "count": 218},
    {"name": "Test 2", "status": "Active",      "count": 1},
]

labels = sorted({each['name'] for each in data})
label_to_idx = {label: idx for idx, label in enumerate(labels)}    # Added
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * len(labels))                         # Modified

for each in data:
    d[each['status']][label_to_idx[each['name']]] = each['count']  # Modified

final_result = {'labels': labels, 'data': []}
for k, v in d.items():
    final_result['data'].append({'name': k, 'data': v})
```

```py
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(final_result)
# {'data': [{'data': [1, 1, 1], 'name': 'Active'},
#           {'data': [40, 1, 0], 'name': 'Failed'},
#           {'data': [85, 0, 0], 'name': 'In Progress'},
#           {'data': [218, 0, 0], 'name': 'Success'}],
#  'labels': ['Test', 'Test 2', 'Test 3']}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please explain one thing what kind of data structure will this line make, multidimensional array or what?
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * len(labels))

Comment: It makes a dictionary that, if key is not found, sets and returns a list of as many 0s as the number of labels.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get unique labels, [**`set comprehension`**](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) can be used. Then you can use [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to from `key:value` pair as each status being key name and count being corresponding values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{"name": "Test 3", "status": "Active", "count": 1}, {"name": "Test 2", "status": "Failed", "count": 1}, {"name": "Test", "status": "In Progress", "count": 85},{"name": "Test", "status": "Failed", "count": 40},{"name": "Test", "status": "Active", "count": 1},{"name": "Test", "status": "Success", "count": 218}, {"name": "Test 2", "status": "Active", "count": 1}]

d = defaultdict(list)
labels = sorted({each['name'] for each in data})

for each in data:
    d[each['status']].append(each['count'])
# -> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Active': [1, 1, 1], 'Failed': [1, 40], 'In Progress': [85], 'Success': [218]})

final_result = {'labels': labels, 'data': []}
for k, v in d.items():
    final_result['data'].append({'name': k, 'data': v})
```

`final_result` would look like:

```
{'labels': ['Test', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'], 'data': [{'name': 'Active', 'data': [1, 1, 1]}, {'name': 'Failed', 'data': [1, 40]}, {'name': 'In Progress', 'data': [85]}, {'name': 'Success', 'data': [218]}]}
```

In order to fill small sized lists with zeros, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111637/11923558).

Comment: thanks for the answer but filling zeros at the end will not give correct data i mean correct position of zeros how can i append 0 in the list at the start so that data remain correct?